# relay prisma graphql update store

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, prisma

I am trying to get prisma and relay working. Here's my repo:

https://github.com/jamesmbowler/prisma-relay-todo

It's a simple todo list. I am able to add the todos, but the ui does not update. When I refresh, the todo is there.

All of the examples of updating the store, that I can find, use a "parent" to the object that is being updated / created.

See https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/mutations.html#using-updater-and-optimisticupdater

Also, the "updater configs" also requires a "parentID". https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/mutations.html#updater-configs

From relay-runtime's RelayConnectionHandler.js comment here:
https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/packages/relay-runtime/handlers/connection/RelayConnectionHandler.js#L232

```
 * store => {
 *   const user = store.get('<id>');
 *   const friends = RelayConnectionHandler.getConnection(user, 'FriendsFragment_friends');
 *   const edge = store.create('<edge-id>', 'FriendsEdge');
 *   RelayConnectionHandler.insertEdgeAfter(friends, edge);
 * }
```

Is it possible to update the store without having a "parent"? I just have todos, with no parent.

Again, creating the record works, and gives this response:

> {   "data" : {
>       "createTodo" : {
>         "id" : "cjpdbivhc00050903ud6bkl3x",
>         "name" : "testing",
>         "complete" : false
>       }   } }

Here's my updater function

```
updater: store => {
          const payload = store.getRootField('createTodo');

          const conn = ConnectionHandler.getConnection(store.get(payload.getDataID()), 'Todos_todoesConnection');

          ConnectionHandler.insertEdgeAfter(conn, payload, cursor);
```

},

I have done a console.log(conn), and it is undefined.

Please help.

----Edit----
Thanks to Denis, I think one problem is solved - that of the ConnectionHandler.

But, I still can't get the ui to update. Here's what I've tried in the updater function:

```
const payload = store.getRootField('createTodo');
const clientRoot = store.get('client:root');
const conn = ConnectionHandler.getConnection(clientRoot, 'Todos_todoesConnection');
ConnectionHandler.createEdge(store, conn, payload, 'TodoEdge');
```

I've also tried this:

```
const payload = store.getRootField('createTodo');
const clientRoot = store.get('client:root');
const conn = ConnectionHandler.getConnection(clientRoot, 'Todos_todoesConnection');
ConnectionHandler.insertEdgeAfter(conn, payload);
```

My data shape is different from their example, as I don't have the 'todoEdge', and 'node' inside my returned data (see above).

> todoEdge {
>           cursor
>           node {
>             complete
>             id
>             text
>           }
>         }

How do I getLinkedRecord, like this?

```
const newEdge = payload.getLinkedRecord('todoEdge');
```

Comment: Who is the parent? Is the `query` or is it any other type of your schema?

Comment: Here's the schema: https://github.com/jamesmbowler/prisma-relay-todo/blob/d0719ed0ae373c90f3d672ee5b600341607988a1/generated/prisma-client/prisma-schema.js#L38 - Yes, query is the parent, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `query` is the parent, the `parentID` will be `client:root`.

Take a look at this: https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/1d72862fa620a9db69d6219d5aa562054d9b93c7/packages/react-relay/classic/store/RelayStoreConstants.js#L18

Also at this issue: https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/2157#issuecomment-385009482

create a `const ROOT_ID = 'client:root';` and pass `ROOT_ID` as your `parentID`. Also, check the name of your connection on the updater, it has to be exactly equal to the name where you declared the query.

**UPDATE**:
Actually, you can import `ROOT_ID` of `relay-runtime`

`import { ROOT_ID } from 'relay-runtime';`

**UPDATE 2**:

Your edit was not very clear for me, but I will provide you an example of it should work ok? After your mutation is run, you first access its data by using `getRootField` just like you are doing. So, if I have a mutation like:

```
  mutation UserAddMutation($input: UserAddInput!) {
    UserAdd(input: $input) {
      userEdge {
        node {
          name
          id
          age
        }
      }
      error
    }
  }
```

You will do:

```
const newEdge = store.getRootField('UserAdd').getLinkedRecord('userEdge');
      connectionUpdater({
        store,
        parentId: ROOT_ID,
        connectionName: 'UserAdd_users',
        edge: newEdge,
        before: true,
      });
```

This `connectionUpdater` is a helper function that looks likes this:

```
export function connectionUpdater({ store, parentId, connectionName, edge, before, filters }) {
  if (edge) {
    if (!parentId) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      console.log('maybe you forgot to pass a parentId: ');
      return;
    }

    const parentProxy = store.get(parentId);

    const connection = ConnectionHandler.getConnection(parentProxy, connectionName, filters);

    if (!connection) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      console.log('maybe this connection is not in relay store yet:', connectionName);
      return;
    }

    const newEndCursorOffset = connection.getValue('endCursorOffset');
    connection.setValue(newEndCursorOffset + 1, 'endCursorOffset');

    const newCount = connection.getValue('count');
    connection.setValue(newCount + 1, 'count');

    if (before) {
      ConnectionHandler.insertEdgeBefore(connection, edge);
    } else {
      ConnectionHandler.insertEdgeAfter(connection, edge);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you, Denis! I think I solved one problem, but still have one remaining - please see my edit.

Comment: This is what my mutation returns: { "data" : { "createTodo" : { "id" : "cjpdbivhc00050903ud6bkl3x", "name" : "testing", "complete" : false } } } So, I don't have an equivalent data structure to your example, so I cannot "getLinkedRecord" ..

Comment: Why do you have this `data` field? It's kind of weird. Couldn't you make your mutation on the server return just and edge instead? A `todoEdge`

Comment: I'm using prisma, so I can't easily change that. https://www.prisma.io/client/client-javascript

Comment: Oh I see. I have no experience with Prisma, but I saw on the link that you provide, an example of running a mutation kind of my example, on `Native GraphQL`.